# Choose elements one by one in dropdown list with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to choose elements in "Category" one-by-one on [this page](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) with:

```
WebElement category = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("tr[__gwt_row='" + rowIndex + "'] > td > div")))
                .get(3);

        category.click();
        category.findElement(By.tagName("select")).sendKeys("Businesses");
        category.click();
        category.findElement(By.tagName("select")).sendKeys("Contacts");
```

Throwing this : "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Maybe exists some another way to do it?

UPD: 
It works if i do this:

```
 WebElement categoryBusinesses = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("tr[__gwt_row='" + rowIndex + "'] > td > div")))
                .get(3);

        categoryBusinesses.findElement(By.tagName("select")).sendKeys("Businesses");

 WebElement categoryContacts = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("tr[__gwt_row='" + rowIndex + "'] > td > div")))
                .get(3);

        categoryContacts.findElement(By.tagName("select")).sendKeys("Contacts");
```

But is it a right way?

UPD2: 
I also tried this:

```
 WebElement element = categoryBusinesses.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
        Select category = new Select(element);
        category.selectByIndex(0);
        category.selectByIndex(1);
```

But it not works.

Comment: I think you need to take a look at how Select elements work in webdriver http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/6426/select-class#t=201611251135026517728 treating them just as a WebElement might lead to some odd behaviour.

Comment: @Josh i have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: After looking at the error: "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document", I have one question. Are you doing any switch window related operation?

Comment: @Shubhasmit No, i don't. Should i do it?

Comment: Check my other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was really annoying... the problem is that every time you change the value of the SELECT, the page is recreating the element thus causing your reference to become stale. You have to refetch it basically every time you interact with it.

I generally make functions out of things like this so that they are reusable.

```
public static void GetCategoriesFromRow(int row)
{
    By locator = By.cssSelector("table[__gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus] tr[__gwt_row='" + row + "'] select");
    for (int i = 0; i < new Select(driver.findElement(locator)).getOptions().size(); i++)
    {
        new Select(driver.findElement(locator)).selectByIndex(i);
        System.out.println(new Select(driver.findElement(locator)).getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
    }
}
```

You call it like

```
driver.get("http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table[__gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus]")));
GetCategoriesFromRow(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement element = categoryBusinesses.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="gwt-debug-contentPanel"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[4]/div/select"));
        Select category = new Select(element);
        category.selectByIndex(0);
        category.selectByIndex(1);
```

This should work.

Comment: Nope, it's not works for me(
The same error: "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"